# Azure DevOps: Android emulator script timeout

Tags: azure-devops

Experiencing continuous timeout errors when using the official bash command for downloading and starting the Android emulator on an Azure DevOps hosted agent using `vmImage: macos-latest`. According to the documentation it should boot an emulator and then continue with the emulator running in background.

This is my definition in our `.yml` file.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

[...]

- script: |
    echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86"
    echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name emu --device "Pixel_API_29_AOSP" -k 'system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86'
    $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -list-avds
  condition: ne(variables.AVD_IMAGES_RESTORED, 'true')
  displayName: 'Download Android Emulator Image'
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: $(JAVA_HOME_8_X64)
    PATH: $(JAVA_HOME_8_X64)/bin:$(PATH)


- script: |
    echo "Starting emulator"
    nohup $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd emu -no-snapshot -no-audio -no-boot-anim -accel auto -gpu auto -qemu -lcd-density 420 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r') ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
    $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices
    echo "Emulator started"
  displayName: 'Android Emulator'
```

And these are the logs that are output until the job gets cancelled due to timeout (60 minutes):

```
Starting: Android Emulator
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash /Users/runner/work/_temp/3b8f2c22-dd8f-40ad-9cf0-972eca407beb.sh
Starting emulator
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

Do anyone have any experience with getting the Android emulator script to work on `macos-latest`? Is there anything we're missing to get it to work properly? Surprised that the script mentioned in the DevOps documentation doesn't work as intended.

Azure DevOps documentation and sample script:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops#test-on-the-android-emulator

Comment: Are the answers helpful to you? Please check the answer, if it is correct, please check it as a correct one. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you.

Comment: This hangs indefinitely for me as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: have you found any solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I changed the vmImage to particular one. Then it worked. You can try other macOS versions, more on that here [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). I also recommend adding echo lines after each problematic command to debug in the pipeline.

```
pool:
  vmImage: macOS-11
```

Comment: This is what ended up working for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by replacing any usages of `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/` with `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/`. For example:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager
```

instead of

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager
```

**Edit:**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SDK="${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager"
AVD="${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager"
EMU="${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/emulator"
ADB="${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/adb"

NAME_EMU="android_emulator"
IMG_EMU="system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"

# Install AVD files
echo "y" | $SDK --install "${IMG_EMU}"

# Create emulator
echo "no" | $AVD create avd -n ${NAME_EMU} -k "${IMG_EMU}" --force

echo ""
echo "List AVDs:"
$EMU -list-avds

# Start emulator in background and with no UI (-no-window), as we're only running database tests.
nohup $EMU -avd ${NAME_EMU} -no-window -no-snapshot -no-audio -no-boot-anim > /dev/null 2>&1 &

$ADB wait-for-device
$ADB shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
$ADB devices
```

Comment: This does not work

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I just checked and this still works in our CI. We're using a `macOS-latest` image on a Microsoft-hosted agent, if that helps.

Comment: I am using Linux agent, it just stuck at one point at end with the above mentioned issue in question.

Comment: Is it still working for you? If so, it would be really appreciated if you could share your full start emulator script. 
I still get a timeout when I use $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/ on macos-latest.

Comment: Hi @LinusHägerbrand , yes this does still work in our CI using the latest MacOS image, I just checked. It was last run on 31st October. I'll see about sharing the script I use, although I don't recall it having any major departures from the sample code in the documentation.